# Is using "out" bad practice

Tags: c#, lambda, moq, anti-patterns

I have just added an **out** bool parameter to a method I've written in order to get a warning in to my UI. I've used an out rather than getting the method itself to return false/true as that would imply the *DoSomething* failed/succeeded. My thinking was that the **warnUser** would indicate what the warning actually was without having to look at the implementation of the method.

**Original Code**

```
public void DoSomething(int id, string input);
```

**New Code**

```
public void DoSomething(int id, string input, out bool warnUser);
```

I'm using Moq to test this code, but it doesn't support out/ref parameters because they're not supported by Lambda expressions

**Test Code**

```
mockService.Verify(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>());
```

So, is using **out** parameters bad practise and if so what do I do instead?

Comment: How does a `bool` "indicate what the warning actually was?"

Comment: @Cody - because it's a meaningful name in my "real" code :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using an out parameter in a void method is generally a bad idea. You say you've used it "rather than getting the method itself to return false/true as that would imply the DoSomething failed/succeeded" - I don't believe that implication is there. Usually in .NET failure is indicated via an exception rather than true/false.

`out` parameters are generally uglier to use than return values - in particular, you have to have a variable of the right type to handle, so you can't just write:

```
if (DoSomething(...))
{
   // Warn user here
}
```

One alternative you might want to consider is an enum indicating the warning level required. For example:

```
public enum WarningLevel
{
    NoWarningRequired,
    WarnUser
}
```

Then the method could return a `WarningLevel` instead of `bool`. That would make it clearer what you meant - although you might want to rename things slightly. (It's hard to give advice with metasyntactic names such as "DoSomething" although I entirely understand why you've used that here.)

Of course, another alternative is that you might want more information to be present - like the *reason* for the warning. That could be done with an enum, or you might want to give some richer result entirely.

Comment: I disagree about the implication of failure. if a method has a bool return, to me that implies a return of false means it failed. But I do agree that failure is generally indicated by an exception being thrown (preferably a strongly typed one). It do like the enum idea though, I should have recognised that myself as I've used that approach in the past. thanks.

Comment: +1 for the `WarningLevel` suggestion. This would eliminate the confusion the asker is concerned about with regards to the return value being interpreted as the success or failure of the function.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as my calling code will be far more readable. "if (!DoSomething(...)" vs "if (DoSomething(...) == WarningLevel.WarnUser)". obviously i'd have something more meaningful that "WarnUser"

Answer (score 9):

`out` is **very much** a useful construct, *in particular* in patterns like `bool TryGetFoo(..., out value)`, where you want to know the "if" and the "what" separately (and nullable isn't necessarily an option).

However - in this case, why not just make it:

```
public bool DoSomething(int id, string input);
```

and use the return value to signal this?

Comment: As I said, I didn't want to imply that the "Something" has failed/succeeded

Comment: @Marc Gravell I would argue that in .NET 4, using a Tuple<bool,MyThing> might be clearer as the input (method arguments) is separated from the output (return values) and still supplies the "if" and "what". And of course, tuples work just fine in lambdas.

Comment: @Antony - I'm not sure I see the significance of that comment; you *do*, however, seem to have exactly one value being returned - why use `out` when you can use `return` for that?

Comment: it just doesn't read right to me. i like my code to read naturally if at all possible. and having "if (!DoSomething(...)" looks like a failure to "do something" to me.

Comment: @Antony - then consider renaming the method so it *does* make sense; or, frankly, get over it ;p A return value doesn't mean "failure" (this isn't C/C++) - it means "here is the return value". The fact that it is a `bool` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Antony (an `Exception` thrown would mean failure)

Comment: I'm with Damian on favouring Tuple. I wish C# would autotranslate that for me like F# does :) Admittedly for TryXXX I may well still use the "standard" pattern simply because these days it *is* a standard pattern :(

Answer (score 4):

A few additional thoughts:

- What FxCop says: [CA1021: Avoid out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx)
- For private/internal methods (implementation details) `out`/`ref` parameters are less of an issue
- [C# 7 Tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) often are a better alternative to `out` parameters
- Further, [C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) improves the handling of `out` parameter on the call site by introducing "out variables" and by allowing to "discard" `out` parameters

Answer (score 2):

Given a big Legacy Code Method (say 15+ lines, legacy code methods with 200+ lines are quite common), one might want to use the "Extract Method" refactoring to clean up and make code less brittle and more maintainable.

Such a refactoring is very likely to produce one or more new methods with out parameters for setting variable values local to the prior method.

Personally, I use this circumstance for a strong indicator that there have been one or more descrete classes hiding in the prior method, so that I can use "Extract class", where in the new class those out parameters get properties visible to the calling (prior) method.

I consider it bad practice to leave the extracted methods with out parameters in the prior method, skipping the coherent following step of "Extract Class", because if you skip it, those local variables remain in your prior function, but do semantically no longer belong to it.

So, in such a scenario, out parameters in my opinion are a code smell breaking SRP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really tough question to answer without knowing more about the context.

If `DoSomething` is a method in the UI layer that is do something which is UI related, then perhaps it's okay. If `DoSomething` is a business layer method though, then this is probably not a good approach because it implies that the business layer needs to understand what an appropriate response might be, and it might even have to be aware if localization issues.

On a purely subjective note, I've tended to stay away from out parameters. I think they disrupt the flow of the code and make it a little less clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to do this is to use expected Exceptions. You can create a set of custom exceptions that define your warnings, and catch them in the calling method.

```
public class MyWarningException : Exception() {}

...

try
{ 
     obj.DoSomething(id,input);
}
catch (MyWarningException ex)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

The idea would be that the exception is raised at the end of the DoSomething implementation, so that the flow doesn't stop in the middle

Comment: An exception should only be thrown if the method can't do what it's meant to, IMO. If it's succeeded but for some reason the user should be given a warning, that doesn't sound like an exceptional situation to me.

Comment: @ykatchou actually it isn't *that* slow; but it is not good practice for general logic flow.

Comment: I can't use an exception as it would have unwanted side effects on my UI code which calls the DoSomething method.

Comment: Jon, an exception indicates a behaviour. If you're expecting that behaviour, then it doesn't mean that the method couldn't do its work??

Comment: what side effects? if you're handling the specific exception, then there are no side effects. if the exception is of other type (whatever it is), then it will bubble up in the call stack as it would normally do

Comment: @Daniel I apologise for giving more context in my question, but my code already handles exceptions. In the controller code (this is within an MVC website) it redirects to a different action depending on whether an exception was handled or not.

Comment: @Daniel: Nothing about the context we've been given indicates that this "display a warning to the user" means "failure". True, we don't have many details here - but from what we've been told, exceptions aren't appropriate in this case.

Comment: oops, that should have read "I apologise for *not* giving more context in my question"

Answer (score -1):

I think the best best solution for your case is to use a delegate instead of bool. Use something like this:

```
public void DoSomething(int id, string input, Action warnUser);
```

You can pass an empty lamda where you don't want to display warnings to user.