# What's the difference between long long and long

Tags: c++, int, long-integer

What's the difference between long long and long?  And they both don't work with 12 digit numbers (600851475143), am I forgetting something?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  long long a = 600851475143;
}
```

Comment: Make that `long long a = 600851475143LL;` and it should work.

Comment: @ildjarn Why would I need to to specify the format using the (LL) postfix, when I have already specified it with a (long long) when declaring the variable?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Going by the standard, all that's guaranteed is:

- `int` must be at least 16 bits
- `long` must be at least 32 bits
- `long long` must be at least 64 bits

On major 32-bit platforms:

- `int` is 32 bits
- `long` is 32 bits as well
- `long long` is 64 bits

On major 64-bit platforms:

- `int` is 32 bits
- `long` is either 32 or 64 bits
- `long long` is 64 bits as well

If you need a specific integer size for a particular application, rather than trusting the compiler to pick the size you want, `#include <stdint.h>` (or `<cstdint>`) so you can use these types:

- `int8_t` and `uint8_t`
- `int16_t` and `uint16_t`
- `int32_t` and `uint32_t`
- `int64_t` and `uint64_t`

You may also be interested in `#include <stddef.h>` (or `<cstddef>`):

- `size_t`
- `ptrdiff_t`

Comment: what do you mean by the "long is either 32 or 64 bits"?  Can it change its bits?

Comment: @Hikari Iwasaki: It depends on the target.  For example, if you're compiling on Windows, it might be 32 bits, while on Linux x86-64, it might be 64 bits.  Types don't change sizes at run-time.

Comment: And g++ even has an `__int128` type, to extend the list...

Answer (score 11):

`long long` does not exist in C++98/C++03, but does exist in C99 and c++0x.

`long` is guaranteed at least 32 bits.

`long long` is guaranteed at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on @ildjarn's comment:

> And they both don't work with 12 digit numbers (600851475143), am I forgetting something?

The compiler looks at the literal value `600851475143` *without considering* the variable that you're assigning it to/initializing it with. You've written it as an `int` typed literal, and it won't fit in an `int`.

Use `600851475143LL` to get a `long long` typed literal.

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ compiler supports long long, that is guaranteed to be at least 64-bits in the C99 standard (that's a C standard, not a C++ standard). See Visual C++  header file to get the ranges on your system.

Recommendation

For new programs, it is recommended that one use only bool, char, int, and double, until circumstance arises that one of the other types is needed.

http://www.somacon.com/p111.php

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your compiler.long long is 64 bits and should handle 12 digits.Looks like in your case it is just considering it long and hence not handling 12 digits.