# What is the difference between type "long" in C++/CLI and C#?

Tags: c#, types, c++-cli, long-integer

In the **C++/CLI** project I have the method `void DoSomething(long x);`. If I want to use it in any unit-test written in **C#**, the method parameter `x` shows up as type `int`.

Why do I have to change the signature to `void DoSomething(long long x);` to use it with parameters of type `long` in my unit-tests (C#)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# `long` is a 64 bit data type.  In C++ All we know about `long` is that it has to hold as much or more than an `int` and it is at least 32 bits.  If you use a `long long` in c++ that is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits which will match what you have in C#.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What is meant, if we write other combinations, e.g., `long int x`?

Comment: @ChristianSt. In C++ there is no difference between `long` and `long int`.  `long` is just the shorthand way to write it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971732/difference-between-long-long-long-long-int-and-long-long-int-in-c

Answer (score 10):

`long` is a keyword both in C# and C++.  They simply don't mean the same thing.  The C++/CLI designers went for the C++ interpretation since C++ was the target interop language.

Not exactly the only unintuitive mapping:

- C# byte => C++/CLI unsigned char
- C# sbyte => C++/CLI char
- C# char => C++/CLI wchar_t
- C# ushort => C++/CLI unsigned short
- C# uint => C++/CLI unsigned int
- C# long => C++/CLI long long
- C# ulong => C++/CLI unsigned long long
- C# string => no equivalent, use System::String^
- C# decimal => no equivalent, use System::Decimal
- C# object => no equivalent, use System::Object^
- C# enum => C++/CLI public enum class
- C# struct => C++/CLI value struct
- C# class => C++/CLI ref class
- C# interface => C++/CLI interface class
- C# nullable types with ? => no equivalent, use Nullable<>

Beware the required `public` keyword for an enum, a necessary evil since C++11 adopted the `enum class` syntax.

Only the void, bool, short, int, float and double keywords match.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a link to that information?

Comment: No, this is original work and not copied from anything.  You'd have to read the entire language specification to find something back, Emca-372.  We create references around here, little point in just reposting existing content.