# argument of a parameterized constructor

Tags: c++11, arguments

can someone explain me how's the argument passed in the 1st parameterized constructor working?

```
public:
//Constructors
Bigint();
Bigint(long long); // 1st parameterized constructor
Bigint(std::string); // 2nd parameterized constructor.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return type"? Constructors have no return type.

Comment: i have updated my question. read it again

Comment: What do you mean by "working"?

Comment: long has been written twice which is confusing since we usually write return type of any variable once.

Comment: "long long" is a type. A different type from "long".

Comment: can you explain it a bit further

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "long", "long long", "long int", and "long long int" in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971732/what-is-the-difference-between-long-long-long-long-int-and-long-long-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long long` is a *type*, just like `int` or `long`. But the difference is that it's at least 64 bits wide.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types.