# What is the difference between long int and long long int?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am using `gcc` version 5.4.0 20160609, 64 bit. When I tried to find the size of `long int` and `long long int` using `sizeof` operator it shows the size as 8 for both `long int` and `long long int`. Then What is the use of this `long long` type qualifier? When does the use of this qualifier come into picture?

The piece of code I used to find the size is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("size of long int: %lu\n", sizeof(long int));
    printf("size of long long int: %lu\n", sizeof(long long int));

    return 0;
}
```

out put is:

```
size of long int: 8
size of long long int: 8
```

Comment: `long long int` rank is greater than `long int` rank, see http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1

Comment: Sizes of the builtin types can depend on the compiler and/or architecture. `long` is 4 bytes large on MinGW.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971732/what-is-the-difference-between-long-long-long-long-int-and-long-long-i

Comment: Within that post there is an answer with a link to the memory model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: Vine, Curios, why did code use `"%lu"`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica result of sizeof is of unsigned type which is usually denoted by size_t

Comment: `"%lu"` matches `unsigned long`.  `"%zu"` matches `size_t`.  Why did code assume `size_t` matched `unsigned long`?