# Storing 2^31 in an `int`

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, bit

Looking at links such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971732/what-is-the-difference-between-long-long-long-long-int-and-long-long-i#:%7E:text=long%20is%20equivalent%20to%20long,is%20at%20least%2064%20bits.), I understand that `unsigned int` in `C++` should be of 16 bits.  As such, the maximum value that it can store should be `32767`.

a.  Why can we store INT_MAX in an int variable, such as:

> int res=INT_MAX;

b. How is the code [like below](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-two/) which calculates the power of `2` valid (runs without any error/warning):

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
        return n>0 && (!(n&n-1));
    }
};
```

because the constraints say: `-2^31 <= n <= 2^31 - 1`, shouldn't we be using `long`?

Comment: Please also leave a comment clarifying my confusion.  Thank you.

Comment: By looking at the pages you linked, I cannot conclude that c++ `unsigned int` is required to be 16 bits. The standard requires it to have **at least** 16 bits.

Comment: @JakobStark, oh, so both the code snippets above are platform dependent?

Comment: For most platforms `unsigned int` has 32 bits (Windows/Linux/MacOS/iOS/Android/...). For example on Arduino it is 16 bits.

Comment: Please page down to the __Properties__ table [Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) `signed int` at least 16. And then check your compiler with `static_assert(sizeof(unsigned int) == 16);`

Comment: The size of `int` (and many more fundamental types) is dependent on the platform you're compiling for. If you need a specific width, use `std::int16_t` or equivalent

Comment: @perivesta: I can't think of a fundamental type that isn't platform dependent in some way. Can you?

Comment: @RichardCritten: Indeed, always 1, but I've worked on a system where there were 64 bits in a byte.

Comment: @RichardCritten, yes, I read that.  But I did not know all modern architectures have use 32 bits for unsigned int.  Everywhere I just encountered values around 2^31 being stored in `int`s.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I've never heard of any platform where `unsigned int` is 16 times the size of `char`.  Probably you meant `CHAR_BITS * sizeof(unsigned int) == 16` or else `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof (uint16_t)`

Comment: @J.Doe by the way that code you linked does not calculate the power of two, but (as the name suggests) checks if a number is a power of two. For non-negative values, this should work independently of the size of integer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the correction.  Am having a bit of brain fade here.

Comment: @Bathsheba technically I think you're right that all are dependent. Although `unsigned char` is always one byte since `sizeof(char) == 1` but bytes that are not octets may exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a. Why can we store INT_MAX in an int variable, such as:
>
> int res=INT_MAX;

`INT_MAX` is the maximum value that can be store in `int`. Per definition that can be stored in an `int`.

> b. How is the code like below which calculates the power of 2 valid (runs without any error/warning):
> ...
>
> because the constraints say: -2^31 <= n <= 2^31 - 1, shouldn't we be using long?

The constraints are wrong. First they assume `int` to be 32bit, which is not the case on e.g. AVR. Second they assume `int` is two's-complement, which is only true since C++20.

It would be more accurate to say the contraints are `INT_MIN <= n <= INT_MAX`. But really what is the point. The argument is `int`. That already says that.

Better would be to use `unsigned int`, `uintmax_t` or a template. There is no reason to limit this function to `int`.

Since C++20 there is `std::has_single_bit` for this.

Comment: "*Second they assume `int` is two's-complement, which is only true since C++20*" - yes, it is only a *guarantee* since C++20. But in *practice*, most common implementations do use two's-complement.