# Checking if a number is odd with n%2 or n&1

Tags: c++, if-statement, operators, bitwise-operators

I was solving https://www.codechef.com/COOK74/problems/TALAZY

First submission (Wrong answer): https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/11557512

Second submission (Accepted): https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/11560985

The change was changing

> if(n % 2){ ...

to

> if(n & 1){ ...

Does it make the difference?

Edit: After people pointed out the change about 'long' to 'long long', I have edited the question.

Comment: Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: The code is same in both cases. So I don't think there is any issue of missing any test cases. My focus is why the change in operator works? both statements work the same.

Comment: You can get rid of the test and write `x = (n+1) >> 1;`

Comment: Nice one. Thanks !

Comment: There are several change between the 2 codes.

Comment: Consider moving the examples into the question body, so that people don't have to risk clicking links to external sites which may contain malware, become unavailable etc.

Comment: How do I move the examples into the question body?

Comment: As of the down-vote, should the question be flagged or deleted by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your wrong answer submission n,m and b are declared as "long" and in the other one it is declared as "long long" , whereas the limit given for them is 10^8. The range of long is platform dependent for more reference u can check "[What's the difference between long long and long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462439/whats-the-difference-between-long-long-and-long)". Try changing it to long long.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take care. Learnt about checking if a number is odd as well as handling overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what the online judge says, the modulus approach is better by a country mile. Although pre C++11, the sign of any remainder is *implementation defined*, this is not relevant when testing that there's no remainder at all. Added to that, from C++11 onwards the sign of the remainder, if any, must match the signed of the input `n`.

The flashier `n & 1` is *implementation-defined* for negative `n`: it depends on whether your platform uses 1's complement, 2's complement or signed-magnitude for signed integral types.

Comment: You mean to say neither of the two is safe in all cases, and "if(n % 2==1)" is the safe way. Is it? Do let me know what is the best way for the same.

Comment: No. They both suffer from being implementation defined. I've pasted up a safe way.

Comment: That is too lengthy to just check if a number is odd or even. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: That's life I'm afraid. Can you get away with an `unsigned` type?

Comment: This is wrong. As of C++11 modulus is now guaranteed to meet the sign of the left hand side. See section 5.6.4 of the C++ standard ([expr.mul]).

Comment: @rapptz: good point, although for some reason, I though that was C++17 onwards. Answer amended

Comment: It is - I'm being spectacularly dumb. Yet another edit and it's time to wiki this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your solution isn't the way you try to figure out whether a number is odd or even.

The problem in a overflow.

In our second solution you changed the value type of counters n,b,m and x from **long** to **long long**. This makes the difference. Indeed you can easily verify also changing the odd/even code in you second solution with the approach you used in your first attempt.

It will return the same results

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take care. Learnt about checking if a number is odd as well as handling overflow.