# Why does C++ programs return a code instead of the answer when it's too big?

Tags: c++

I am coding a C++ program to calculate a math problem. I first write:

```
int x = 1
int y = 1
int z = 1
int answer = x * y * z
cout << answer << endl;
```

And when I build and run that, it prints 1. But when I do this:

```
   int x = 1234;
    int y = 5243;
    int z = 1142;
    int answer =  x * y * z;
    cout << answer << endl ;
```

It prints out instead a answer, which is 7388502404, but a code I don't understand: "-1201352188".
Could you explain why does this code happens, and how to solve the code?

Comment: Typically `int` can only hold numbers up to about 2.2 billion.after you pass that things get... [weird](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: In this case you get 7,388,582,404, too big. But if you look at that as a hexadecimal number you get 1 B8 64 D2 04. The usual behaviour is  B8 64 D2 04 sits in the 32 bit integer and the 1 vanishes into the ether. Convert back to decimal notation and you get -1201352188. This is what usually happens with a signed integer, but it's left up to whatever's beneath C++to decide what actually happens.

Comment: A note on the duplicate: a smaller type is being used, but the result is the same and the answer covers what's happening right down to the bits.

Comment: The result of `1234*5243*1142` exceeds the maximum that an `int` can represent on your platform  (the standard only guarantees that an `int` can represent up to `32767`, although it appears your compiler has a 32-bit `int` that can represent up to about `2147483647`) so you get overflow.   Formally, overflow of signed integral types is undefined behaviour (although that may change in a future standard).   A typical result (not guaranteed by the standard) is a value that is very different than you expect (in your case, a large negative), such as truncating the result to fit in an `int`.

Comment: Also consider this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462474/12861639 if you want to set the max sizes for you numbers for sure.

Comment: Your C++ code should not even compile (missing semicolons). Check by reading [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) then try to compile using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use a debugger (such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ...) to understand the behavior of your C++ code.  Next time, provide some [mre] in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a code, it's the value as stored in the integer result. You're experiencing integer overflow. An `int` can only hold values of a certain size, and when you exceed that size you end up with bit patters that aren't what you want but that are still storable in an `int`. Sometimes those bit patterns are the integer representations of negative numbers which is what's happened here.

You might consider using a larger integer type such as `long` or `long long`.

Comment: Note that you'll want that larger data type the whole way through. If you multiply 3 `int`s the multiplication will be done as `int` and will overflow before it can be stored in the larger type.

Comment: @user4581301 That's actually not true. When you do a `long * int` or `int * long`, the `int` would actually be cast into `long` and make it into a `long * long`. However, it is true that you might want to cast them manually, or even declare them into the same type, to eliminate any unintended behaviors

Comment: Another possibility is using some [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library such as [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep what you say is true, but that doesn't make my statement untrue. Multiply three `int`s and you will get an `int`. Them's the rules. Change one or more of those `int`s into a `long` and you'll get the behaviour you've described, but you've fundamentally changed the parameters.

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, it was my bad, I thought you meant `int(3) * long(num)` for some reason