# Difference between long and long long

Tags: c, types, integer

> what is the difference between The long and long long.
> i'm using 64bit windows sysem.
> for me sizes and ranges of long and long long are same.
> Answer me in detail

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("long size: %d\n",sizeof(long));
    printf("long long size: %d\n\n",sizeof(long long));
    long value1=9223372036854775807;
    long long value2=9223372036854775807;
    printf("Max Limits\n");
    printf("value1: %li\n",value1);
    printf("value2: %lli\n\n",value2);
    //overflow of the range
    value1++;
    value2++;
    printf("value1: %li\n",value1);
    printf("value2: %lli\n",value2);

    
    /* OutPut OutPut OutPut
    long size: 8
    long long size: 8

    Max Limits
    value1: 9223372036854775807
    value2: 9223372036854775807
 
    value1: -9223372036854775808
    value2: -9223372036854775808*/

}
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462439/whats-the-difference-between-long-long-and-long

Comment: I can't understand it

Comment: the answer tells you all you need to know: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462474/453348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C types are intended to be flexible, so they can be adapted to different situations in different C implementations. Because of this, in some C implementations, `long` and `long long` are the same width (number of bits used for the value) and size (total number of bytes, including padding). (Some other types can be the same size. For example, `short` and `int` can be the same.)

In a C implementation where `long` and `long long` are the same width and size, there is no arithmetic difference between them. There are technical differences. In particular, a pointer to a `long` is a different type from a pointer to a `long long`, and you should not use one where the other is expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Difference between `long` and `long long`.

`long` has a minimum range of +/-(2<sup>31</sup> - 1).

`long long` has a minimum range of +/-(2<sup>63</sup> - 1).

Code below has different portability.

```
long      value1 = 9223372036854775807;  // Not always portable.
long long value2 = 9223372036854775807; // OK
```

---

Even when `long` and `long long` have the same range, (they may differ in other implementations), they remain different types and so create different functionality with `_Generic`.

```
#define foo(X) _Generic((X), \
long: "Blue", \
long long: "No red!" \
)

int main() {
  puts(foo(1L));
  puts(foo(1LL));
}
```

Output

```
Blue
No red!
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, answer amended.