# why reference size is always 4 bytes - c++

Tags: c++, reference

On a 32-bit machine  I always get the `sizeof` of a reference 4 bytes even if it's a reference to a double, so what does it really store in this 4 bytes.

**EDIT :**

```
class A{
public:
  double&  a;
};

int main(){
  cout << sizeof(A) << endl; // this will print out 4
}
```

Comment: You can't get the size of a reference, because a reference is not an object. Please show us what code you are testing with.

Comment: Because your question makes no sense. As @R.MartinhoFernandes says, you can't get the size of a reference. So unless you post some code showing what you're actually *doing*, we have no clue what you're asking, or how to answer it

Comment: Hi AlexDan - try uploading some of your code and hopefully some of the downvoters will undo their downvotes. Point out the particular bit of the code where you expected a different result and let us know what you expected and why.

Comment: I've updated MY Question with a sample of my code.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The standard is pretty clear on `sizeof` (C++11, 5.3.3/4):

> When applied to a reference or a reference type, the result is the
>   size of the referenced type.

So if you really are taking `sizeof(double&)`, the compiler is telling you that `sizeof(double)` is 4.

**Update:** So, what you really are doing is applying `sizeof` to a class type. In that case,

> When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an
>   object of that class [...]

So we know that the presence of the reference inside `A` causes it to take up 4 bytes. That's because even though the standard does not mandate how references are to be implemented, the compiler still has to implement them somehow. This somehow might be very different depending on the context, but for a reference member of a class type the only approach that makes sense is sneaking in a `double*` behind your back and calling it a `double&` in your face.

So if your architecture is 32-bit (in which pointers are 4 bytes long) that would explain the result.

Just keep in mind that *the concept* of a reference is not tied to any specific implementation. The standard allows the compiler to implement references however it wants.

Answer (score 33):

You can't, and it isn't.

A C++ reference is *not* a pointer. It is an alias of an object. *Sometimes*, the compiler chooses to implement this by using a pointer. But often, it implements it by *doing nothing at all*. By simply generate code which refers directly to the original object.

In any case, `sizeof` applied to a reference type *does not give you the size of a reference*. So it's not really clear what you're doing, making it impossible to explain what is happening.

**Edit**

Now that you've shown some code, we can answer the question:

You are taking the size of a class containing a reference. As I said above, a reference is not a pointer, but when necessary, the compiler may fall back to using a pointer to represent it. When you create a class containing a reference, the only (sane) way the compiler can implement it is by defining a class which holds the address of an object. On 32-bit systems, addresses are 32 bits, or 4 bytes, wide. So `sizeof` such a class will (typically) be 4.

Comment: Wrong on so many levels. "Sometimes, the compiler chooses to implement this by using a pointer. But often, it implements it by doing nothing at all." That is in no way different from an integer, or anything else. Unless you agree that `int i=1;` doesn't declare anything (at least if you don't change `i` later`), you can't say a reference is nothing at all.

Comment: Sure I can. If you do something like this: `int i = 0; int& r = i`, then compilers will typically *not* generate code for putting a pointer to `i` on the stack. Instead, subsequent operations on `r` (say, `r++`) will just emit the *exact* same code as if you'd written `i++` A reference is just an alias.

Comment: A reference is exactly a pointer. Any optimization a compiler can do with `int i; int&r = i`, it can do with `int i; int* r = &i`. Any optimization it cannot do with a pointer, it cannot do with a reference. The problem of pointer aliasing is present in full with references as well.

Comment: No it isn't. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @StefanDragnev Mechanically, compilers will typically implement references with pointers, but that doesn't mean they're the same thing.  If the reference doesn't actually need to be a distinct entity, such as in jalf's `int i = 0; int& r = i;` example, there's (to my knowledge) nothing in the standard preventing the compiler from treating `r` as syntactic sugar for `i`, and just silently substituting `i` when you use `r`.