# How to give a new name to object's member

Tags: c++

Is there any way i can give a new name to existing object's member so this name is visible only in current and/or inner scope (without using #define or creating new variables):

```
class foo
{
  public:
    int verylongclassmembername;
};

foo f;
// typedef f.verylongclassmembername t;
// t = 56;

{
  // t = 79; // also visible
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what scope excatly you want the replacement name inside. The proposed solution will work in function scope, but then you added the reference in your struct, defeating the puropse of "saving memory". What *exactly* do you want to acheive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int &shortRef = f.verylongclassmembername;
```

Comment: thanks! does creating reference means memory allocation? or it's just compiler directive?

Comment: @user2543574, the reference will be a variable with auto storage (on the stack) in this case. Although the compiler may optimize it away.

Comment: @StoryTeller is there any other way i can achieve this using only standard c++ directives like typedef?

Comment: References are part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @user2543574, what Alexandre said

Comment: struct data_struct{int& data0;int& data1;};. sizeof(data_struct) == 8 on my machine. why?

Comment: @user2543574 To answer your why, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446907/why-reference-size-is-always-4-bytes-c However, size of reference is irrelevant here, since compiler should optimize such reference to no operation - assembly code should be identical with int &shortRef = f.verylongclassmember; or without it.