# Does reference variable occupy memory?

Tags: c++

I have read that **reference variable shares the same memory address** with the original variable but also takes up some space on the stack.
And as reference has the same memory address as the original variable, it is also known as alias.

So, my question is **how memory allocations are done for reference variables** ?

Comment: I believe references are usually implemented as a pointer, so it's as big as a pointer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446907/why-reference-size-is-always-4-bytes-c

Comment: @Steve I think, reference is not a pointer. It is an alias. If we think it as a pointer, it should be const pointer.

Comment: The implementation behind the scenes may be with a pointer, but in the language rules, you are right. See FredOverflow's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

8.3.2 References §4

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage

That being said, if a reference needs storage, it typically needs as much storage as a pointer:

```
struct P
{
    int* p;
};

struct R
{
    int& r;
};

static_assert(sizeof(P) == sizeof(R), "sizeof(P) == sizeof(R)");
```

Answer (score 2):

If the passed variable is located in memory, then a reference to that variable is usually a pointer, which could be kept in register or stored in memory. If the passed variable is located in a register due to compiler optimization, then a reference to that variable will use the same register.