# Reference parameter returning copy

Tags: c++

For whatever reason, this reference parameter is returning a copy. So when I alter OutWeapon for index 0, it doesn't affect Weapon1. Am I doing this wrong?

```
class ULoadout
{
public:
    ULoadout();

    FWeaponSlot Weapon1;
    FWeaponSlot Weapon2;
    FWeaponSlot Weapon3;
    FWeaponSlot Weapon4;

    FSkillSlot Skill1;
    FSkillSlot Skill2;
    FSkillSlot Skill3;
    FSkillSlot Skill4;

    void GetWeapon(int32 InIndex, FWeaponSlot& OutWeapon);
    void GetSkill(int32 InIndex, FSkillSlot& OutSkill);
};

void ULoadout::GetWeapon(int32 InIndex, FWeaponSlot& OutWeapon)
{
    switch (InIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        OutWeapon = Weapon1;
        break;

    case 1:
        OutWeapon = Weapon2;
        break;

    case 2:
        OutWeapon = Weapon3;
        break;

    case 3:
        OutWeapon = Weapon4;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are `Skill2` etc public? Why are you not using an array?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to assign a reference `Weapon1` to another reference `OutWeapon` and it doesn't do what you expect it to do. In C++ it is not possible to rebind references. assignment to reference always causes an assignment to the referenced object.

Comment: When you call `GetWeapon()`, you allocate memory for `OutWeapon` and then pass. What you really need is to return a pointer.

Comment: reference cannot be rebind. you might want pointer or `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: or simply array: `FWeaponSlot weapons[4]; FWeaponSlot& GetWeapon(int32 i) { return weapons[i]; }`

Comment: Perhaps you should actually ***return*** a reference instead?

Comment: ^That. Why do you return `void` and have an output parameter? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810797/which-is-better-return-value-or-out-parameter) is C# but the same applies

Comment: If all the members are public, you don't even *need* a getter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactoring to

```
FWeaponSlot& ULoadout::GetWeapon(int32 InIndex)
```

is the sensible, and idiomatic, way of doing this. (C++ does not allow you rebind references.)

Comment: Should be mentioned, though, that the copying problem remains, if the result is not assigned to a reference again. If the target is a member of another class with independent lifetime (i. e. the member can exist before being assgned), it must be a pointer...

Comment: @Sean: I'd be inclined to chuck out an exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, a reference parameter can only be used to alter te object it references, but not to assign the refernce in the caller to a different object. For this, a pointer is necessary, which can be done as follows.

```
void ULoadout::GetWeapon(int32 InIndex, FWeaponSlot*& OutWeapon)
{
    switch (InIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        OutWeapon = &Weapon1;
        break;
    case 1:
        OutWeapon = &Weapon2;
        break;
    case 2:
        OutWeapon = &Weapon3;
        break;
    case 3:
        OutWeapon = &Weapon4;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

The caller would also need to give the address of the object to be exchanged. However, a different solution like returning a reference to the desired object or simply using an array index might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how you call `getWeapon` function:

```
ULoadout u; // where ever you got it from...

FWeaponSlot s; // you need a true object!!!
u.getWeapon(0, s); // now you pass the true object in as reference!
```

What now happens in `getWeapon` effectively is:

```
s = weapon1;
```

Be aware that `s` is an object, not a reference, so you copy `u.weapon1` into `s`...

To avoid this problem in the specific case you need a pointer instead:

```
FWeaponSlot* s = u.getWeapon(0);
```

Notice that I silently changed the signature (just for convenience on calling)...

`u` remains the owner of the objects and will clean them up automatically when being destroyed, so there is no need for any kind of smart pointers in this specific case. Just make sure that you do not use the `s` pointer after the lifetime of `u` ended...

Answer (score 0):

Whereas taking `FWeaponSlot*&` would solve your issue, I suggest to use regular getter instead:

```
class ULoadout
{
    FWeaponSlot weapons[4];
    FSkillSlot skills[4];
public:
    ULoadout();

    const FWeaponSlot& GetWeapon(int32 index) const { return weapons[index]; }
    FWeaponSlot& GetWeapon(int32 index) { return weapons[index]; }
    const FSkillSlot& GetSkill(int32 index) const { return skills[index]; }
    FSkillSlot& GetSkill(int32 index) { return skills[index]; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using a reference then change the method to:

```
FWeaponSlot& ULoadout::GetWeapon(int32 InIndex);
```

However, you'll need to check that `InIndex` is valid within the method as you have no way of returning a value that indicates "no weapon".You'll want something like this at the top of the method:

```
if(InIndex > 3) throw std::out_of_range("invalid weapon index");
```

The other alternative is to return a pointer, and have `null` indicate "no weapon":

```
FWeaponSlot* ULoadout::GetWeapon(int32 InIndex);
```